# onclick return confirm is not working

Tags: javascript, onclick, confirm

**Overview:**

I am using an anchor link here in my code to navigate to my delete script but before running the script I want javascript to come up with a popup that says are you sure to delete, and thus on confirmation goes and delete the data by running the script I wrote in delete_subject.php.

**Problem:**

When I click on the anchor tag, it doesn't bring the popup but runs the script directly and deletes the data. So, why does the JavaScript not run?

**Code:**

```
    <a href="delete_subject.php?
    subject=<?php echo $current_subject["id"];?>"
    onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?");">Delete subject</a>
```

Comment: You've double `"` in side `"`, can you please look at the code in a decent ide or a simple text editor with a decent code highlighter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're nesting your quotes incorrectly.

Try this instead:

```
<a href="delete_subject.php?
subject=<?php echo $current_subject["id"];?>"
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Delete subject</a>
```

When inside double quotes, you'll have to use single quotes to work with strings in JavaScript.

Comment: You're welcome! If it isn't too much trouble, would you mind accepting my answer if it helped you?

Comment: sure buddy. I was just waiting for the 9 minutes zone to passby. 
as stackoverflow doesn't allow you to accept an answer before 10 minutes of posting the question.